# How to call Generic Portlet methods from servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, liferay, liferay-6, portlet

I have created a portlet and able all my business logic is performing in a servlet. I need to get the liferay login user details in the servlet. SO I have created a class which will extend the `GenericPortlet`. Now My question is how can I call that class I need to execute the GenericPorlet unimplemented method. My code is as follows,

```
public class ActionProcess extends GenericPortlet {

    public void init() throws PortletException{
        super.init();
    }

    public void doView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) throws PortletException, IOException {
             User user = (User) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.USER);
             ThemeDisplay td  =(ThemeDisplay)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
             User urs = td.getUser();
             System.out.println("doView "+ urs);
             System.out.println("doView "+ user);
    }
}
```

Now I need to call the `doView()` and return the values to servlet. How can I do that my servlet code is.

```
@WebServlet("/demoClass")
public class demoClass extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public demoClass() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 doPost(request, response); // 
        }
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
//Here I am performing the business logic....
//How do I call the ActionProcess class here, I need to get the User name which is return by diView() method
}
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, and my answer is very similar to my answer to your [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28536573/how-to-pass-values-from-jsp-to-servlet-without-performing-event/28536930).

It's the *framework's* (portal's) business to call the lifecycle methods of a portlet. *Not* yours.

You need to rethink your problem and come up with a different architecture. Or give us your problem to suggest a different solution than the one that you're currently pursuing.

Differing from that answer, I'm assuming that in this case you're within the very same same web application (portlet and servlet are deployed in the same webapp). However, just like in that [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28536573/how-to-pass-values-from-jsp-to-servlet-without-performing-event/28536930), a portlet's request is routed through the portal while the servlet's request is not. You'll not have the data available.

Comment: Thank you. my problem is, I am using Orbeon form builder as a portlet on Liferay. so that the user can login with liferay portal and fill the form and they click save button. On click of save button the values should save the orbeon will send the form details in XML format. So I have created a servlet in a separate porlet and passing that XML to that servlet. there I am parsing the xml and need to save in db based on log in user site that is I am planning to save the form values in different databases based on their organization. Any suggestions please

Comment: OR can it possible perform my business in view.jsp (with out creating servlet in the porlet. But How can I receive form data as input stream)?  please help me out this

Comment: How about deploying Orbeon Forms as a portlet? http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/admin/deployment-portlet

Comment: Yes That's what I did now. I have created a proxy portlet for form runner. and configured respective form in respective page. Now Let's say In events page Events form is displaying now. So the users can fill the form data and they will click save. On click of save the orbeon form runner will send the form info in XML format. So Now I need to extract the XML and save the form data in different DB's based on user's organization.

Comment: Can it possible to receive XML form data in portlet(view.jsp) and perform business logic there and save the values in DB?

Comment: You might have more success asking an Orbeon-Forms specific question rather than the very generic question that you ask here. I recommend that you rather describe the problem you're trying to solve, not ask for how to do the implementation that you intend - the solution might be totally different from what you envision