# How to pass values from JSP to Servlet without performing event?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, liferay

I have crated a portlet, Where I am doing my business logic in servlet. But I am getting the liferay login user details in the jsp page. So Now I need to pass the user details while hitting the servlet. This is my JSP code,

```
<%
 String fullname= user.getFullName();
 out.println("Full name is: "+fullname+ "...");
 long id = themeDisplay.getLayout().getGroupId();
 out.println("Site ID is: "+id+ "...");
 long userId = themeDisplay.getUserId();
 out.println("User ID is: "+userId+ "...");
 %>
```

I need to access the above details in the servlet. How can I do that? Each login user has some different credentials, So all the values should update in and need to access in the servlet. what is the best way to access these values without performing any event. I am hitting the servlet from another web service. I need to access in Get OR Post method,

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                 doPost(request, response);
//I need to access those login user information here.. 
        }
```

Comment: crossreferencing a very similar question that comes from the opposite direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28536397

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be really hard to do ("really hard" as in "almost impossible"): When you're in a servlet, all the portal's code of identifying the actual user won't run.

In fact, when you look at the HttpServletRequest for a portlet: This will be directed towards the portal and only later be forwarded to the portlet, with the properly constructed context (e.g. logged in user).

When you look at the servlet, this will be directed to your servlet. Your servlet typically lives in a totally different application context. Thus - by servlet specification - it will be totally separated from the portal environment.

Everything that you find to mitigate this limitation will be somewhat of a hack. Some people use cookies or request parameters. But they all are introducing more or less problems. Especially when you speak of webservices that access your servlet, you can't go with cookies.

In the interest of a well maintainable implementation, my recommendation is to change your architecture. Unfortunately you don't give enough context to recommend what to change your architecture to.